# How do I retrieve the starred questions?

Tags: support, bookmarks

I hope this is the right place to ask. If not I will delete and ask somexhere else (where though?). I noticed there is a star I can click next to vote arrows close to questions title. So I thought I could bookmark them this way, but I cannot see any effect, nor can I find a list where those marked questions would appear. I am using a mobile phone, Firefox 66 on Android. Thanks.

EDIT: While the duplicate question does exist, there is no valid answer there. The favorite tab is absent from my layout, as far as I can tell. Does mobile version of the site offer it?

Comment: I edited that the said question does not answer my issue.

Comment: So [this link](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/230132/exocytosis?tab=favorites) or [this link](https://stackexchange.com/users/15804951/exocytosis?tab=favorites) doesn't take you anywhere?  On Chrome mobile, you can access it from the "Activity" tab of your user page, and there is a dropdown that should be on "Summary", you can drop it down to "Favorites"

Comment: Ah thanks for the dropdown thing, that solved my problem.

Comment: @JMac I'm curious why you voted to close the question and yet also posted an answer, in the comment section no less?

Comment: @DavidZ Huh?  I posted a suggested duplicate, and OP tried to say it didn't solve their issue, but I was pretty sure it did so I was just trying to point out where favourites are on mobile.  I'm not sure what you expected me to do here?  Should I have marked it as a duplicate then ignored OP when they couldn't figure out the link on mobile?  Should I have posted an answer essentially repeating Manishearth's answer?

Comment: @JMac Well... it looks to me like "where favorites are on mobile" is exactly what was being asked here, or at least the main part of it. Personally I'm not sure whether this is a duplicate, but if you think it is one (enough to vote accordingly), then my suggestion would indeed be to ignore the OP's being unable to figure out the link, or at least respond in a way that doesn't answer the question - perhaps something along the lines of "If you edit your question to focus on that, you may get the hold removed".

Comment: @DavidZ Well that just seems unnecessarily unhelpful to me, I don't see why I would be expected to do that.  OP tried to clear up the question after, but his actual concern seemed trivial, so I treated it that way.  If you really think it's an issue, go ahead and delete my comment?

Comment: @JMac: "his actual concern seemed trivial" Why is finding my starred questions more trivial than anything else on this site? And the other questions did not seem to provide a satisfactory solution to my problem, unlike your comment.

Comment: @Exocytosis Trivial in the sense you just didn't see a dropdown.

Comment: @JMac: I see. A tab is not a dropdown list though, and the only answer present in the "duplicate" does not mention it, although the second link with network wide favorite actually works. So how do we add the information and where? In a comment below that answer?